# HDFS path changing when trying to update files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am new to Hadoop and HDFS, so maybe it is something I am doing wrong when I copy from local (Ubuntu 10.04) to HDFS on a single node on localhost.  The initial copy works fine, but when I modify my local input folder and try to copy back to HDFS, the HDFS path changes.

```
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/anagram /user/hduser/anagram
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/anagram
Found 1 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup    4067675 2011-08-29 05:44 /user/hduser/anagram/SINGLE.TXT
```

After adding another file (COMMON.TXT) to the same local directory, I run the same copy on the local directory to HDFS, but this time it copies to a different location than the first time (/user/hduser/anagram to /user/hduser/anagram/anagram).

```
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/anagram /user/hduser/anagram
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/anagram
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup    4067675 2011-08-29 05:44 /user/hduser/anagram/SINGLE.TXT
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2011-08-29 05:48 /user/hduser/anagram/anagram
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/anagram/anagram
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup     805232 2011-08-29 05:48 /user/hduser/anagram/anagram/COMMON.TXT
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup    4067675 2011-08-29 05:48 /user/hduser/anagram/anagram/SINGLE.TXT
```

Has anyone ran into this?  I found that to resolve this, you need to remove the first directory and then copy over again:

```
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -rmr /user/hduser/anagram/anagram
Deleted hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/anagram/anagram
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -rmr /user/hduser/anagram
Deleted hdfs://localhost:54310/user/hduser/anagram
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/anagram /user/hduser/anagram
~$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/anagram
Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup     805232 2011-08-29 05:55 /user/hduser/anagram/COMMON.TXT
-rw-r--r--   1 hduser supergroup    4067675 2011-08-29 05:55 /user/hduser/anagram/SINGLE.TXT
```

Does anyone know how to do this without having to delete the directory every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that this is side effect (check the FileUtil.java, static method   FileUtil.checkDest(String srcName, FileSystem dstFS, Path dst, boolean overwrite) )
try this:

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal /tmp/anagram/*.TXT /user/hduser/anagram
```

for updating directory.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Gave the message that "Target /user/hduser/anagram/SINGLE.TXT already exists" and did not create a new nested directory